# Trying to execute a function through a users choice with the select command Bash

Tags: bash, function, shell, select

I am trying to get a function to execute after a user makes a selection from a menu, but I am having trouble figuring out what I am supposed to do to get it to execute. All I am getting is the program performing an echo of the function name.

```
#!/bin/bash

function task1 {
echo "Hello"
}

function task2 {
echo "how  are you"
}

function task3 {
echo "Im good thanks for asking"
}




PS3='Please select one of the options: '
select _ in \
  'Exit program' \
  'task1' \ 
  'task2' \
  'task3' \

do
  case $REPLY in
    1) echo exit ;;
    2) echo task1 ;;
    3) echo task2 ;;
    4) echo task3 ;;
    *) echo 'Invalid selection, please try again.' ;;
  esac
done
```

Output

```
1) Exit program
2) Find the even multiples of any number.
3) Find the terms of any linear sequence given the rule Un=an+b.
4) Find the numbers that can be expressed as the product of two nonnegative integers in succession and print them in increasing order.
Please select one of the options: 1
exit
Please select one of the options: 2
task1
Please select one of the options: 3
task2
Please select one of the options: 4
task3
Please select one of the options: .
Invalid selection, please try again.
Please select one of the options:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case` block has a bunch of `echo` calls. Get rid of those.

Functions mimic regular commands. To call them you just write the function name. Don't put `echo` as that's going to just print a message.

```
case $REPLY in
  1) exit ;;
  2) task1 ;;
  3) task2 ;;
  4) task3 ;;
  *) echo 'Invalid selection, please try again.' ;;
esac
```